# Ajax call not working in safari and firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari

I'm trying to make an ajax call in my code, it works fine in Chrome but doesn't work in safari and Firefox. I tried to find out if it's firing the click event, it was logging "here" but the ajax call is not fired.
Here's my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tPlaylist', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("here");
   var current = myPlaylist.playlist[myPlaylist.current];
     $.get("/tracks/" + parseInt(current.id) + "/playlist", null);
});
```

Comment: difficult to say with that code example - what is myPlaylist? Does myPlaylist has a property current, if so, does current exist in the array/object? And what should happen, $.get has no function in it? Evaluate if you get an error, or provide an example which shows the described behavior.

Comment: I'm using a plugin called jPlayer which I'm customizing to have an add to playlist button. The myPlaylist comes from JPlayer and calling current on it is how to get a currently playing track on the playlist.

Comment: I've fixed the problem. I had to be logged in to the app for me to access that endpoint. It was not an ajax problem